# Are there inflectives in Russian?

Tags: грамматика, морфология

Recently I learned that there is a special form of verbs in German, called "inflective", which emerged in German language just recently (less than 60 years ago), and that they sometimes grupped with interjections.

I was told that a similar form exists in Russian as well. Is it true?

For example,

Inflective - Noun - Verb

```
прыг - прыжок - прыгать
скок - скачок - скакать
хлоп - хлопок - хлопать
шлёп - шлепок - шлёпать
кувырк - кувырок - кувыркать
цап - (no form) - цапать
царап - (no form) - царапать
тук - (no form) - тукать
```

I wonder what other words can be added to expand this list?

Added as a result of the dicussion:

```
хвать - хваток - хватать
глядь - взгляд - глядеть
```

P.S. I looked up "кувырк" in a [dictionary](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/179410/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BA) and it describes this word as either predicative (another part of speech) or interjection. There are no examples, so I wonder how to determine whether we are facing the first or the letter. Intuitively predicative (or predicative adverb) would be in phrase like "мне кувырк", although this sounds unnatural, and inflective (or inflective interjection) would be in phrase like "он кувырк, и убежал".

**UPDATE** It has been pointed to me that some of these forms "хвать", "глядь" are actually contractions of second person verbs. This process can be seen in phrases like "а он возьми да и прыгни".

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_yyivilKpo

Comment: grupped => grouped?

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption is absolutely valid. Since yes, in Russian some interjection can be treated and used as specific verbal forms.

These are so called "глагольные междометия", or "междометные глаголы", or even "глагольно-междометные формы".

Еxamples:

> - Я его как **шмяк** в лицо.
> - А она вдруг **бултых** в воду.
> - И ни с того ни с сего, учитель **хлоп** его по шее!

The majority of such interjections are onomatopoeic (звукоподражательные), like "бах", "кряк" and so on. Members of this group in scientific articles are also called "вербализованные звукоподражания". Though there exists second form of verbal interjections, derived from "real", "full-fledged", verbs, among them I can recall pretty popular "глядь" и "хвать" (in addition to кувырк, mentioned in the question).

These interjections are very special, they does not express any kind of grammatical category, (such as person, number, gender, case etc.), with some important clauses, which are:

- [Tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense), which is most likely past tense. You can say "хлопнул" instead of "хлоп", but you can not say "хлопаю". Also, one can imagine usage as a future tense verb. ("Он тогда скажет, что это его не касается, а ты тогда щёлк затвором пистолета, припугнёшь его").
- [Mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood), which is always indicative (изъявительное наклонение), that means such verbs (and relative interjections) always express some specific fact or action.
- Aspect, which is always [perfective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfective_aspect) (глаголы совершенного вида).

Comment: You can very much easy say "хлопаю", this word and "хлопнул" both being verbs, not interjections!

Comment: nobody argues, @Anixx, that's what I'm talking about actually. This verb is interchangeable with verbal interjection. But it is used mostly like verb in past tense. If you can provide an example where such interjection can be replaced by presence tense, please, provide it.

Comment: Future: «А мы с тобой вдвоем предполагаем жить, и *глядь* — как раз — умрем» (Пушкин) (here before comma it's present tense and after the comma - future).

Comment: Present: «...ездит на извозчике, каждый день ты доставай в кеятр билет, а там через неделю, *глядь* ― и посылает на толкучий продавать новый фрак» (Гоголь)

Comment: Confusingly, in the first case (future), «глядь» can be substituted by «глядишь». In the second case (present), such substitution would require changing the tense of the final clause to future (becoming «...*глядишь* - и *пошлёт* на толкучий...»).

Comment: @artm, nice points, good for me I've said "most likely" past" and also mentioned future tense. Still, present tense is extremely rare. You perfect examples rather indicate the fact that for some verbal interjection tense is a very loose concept.

Comment: There is a specific narrational style or mode in Russian, often used in jokes («анекдоты») and tales («сказки»), where events of the past (or of fantasy) are recounted using present tense. It is quite common to use "verbal interjections" in this style. Like «...катится, катится, глядь, а на встречу ему лиса...»

Comment: Present: «Потому как она в это время шмяк... ту-дыть, сподыть, ёксель-моксель, ерш твою медь... Ш-ш-ш! И ждешь, пока остынет.»