# Why 2nd person verb form is used for 3rd person here?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

I wonder how this usage of 2nd person verbs for 3rd person is called? Are these words still remain verbs or become [inflective interjections](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/983/are-there-inflectives-in-russian)?

- А он возьми да и прыгни.
- Отвязав мешок, уронил его на землю, а он как завопи.
- Григорян, вот он, засуетился, затрясся, потом как завопи, угрожая мне выдворением...
- Я и чуть расслабился - а зря, на светофоре это чудо вдруг как прыгни назад!

Or this is a special grammatical voice, similar to "сообрази он вовремя..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the so called *прошедшее время мгновенно-произвольного действия*.

Vinogradov, *Русский язык*, § 50:

> Другая форма прошедшего времени, еще живая в стилях разговорной речи, но обычно не выделяемая грамматиками русского языка (за исключением синтаксиса А. А. Шахматова), относится к категории совершенного вида. Она не имеет ни родовых, ни числовых различий. Лица обозначаются аналитически — местоименными префиксами или в 3-м лице — также существительными. Эта форма прошедшего времени очень экспрессивна и по внешнему облику совпадает с формой повелительного наклонения единственного числа глаголов совершенного вида, но отличается от императивной формы особой интонацией неожиданности, например:
>
> - Тот-то на старости лет да польстись на его богатства *(Островский, "Бедность не порок")*
> - Я шутить ведь не умею и вскочи ему на шею *(Ершов, "Конек-Горбунок")*

which means:

> Another perfective past tense form still lives in colloquial speech but is not usually separated by Russian language grammatists (except Shakhmatov's studies). It varies neither in gender nor number. Person is expressed analytically (through pronominal prefixes) or, for the third persons, also through nouns. This very expressive form is identical in appearance to singular perfective imperative but unlike the latter conveys the meaning of suddenness. E.g.:
>
> - Тот-то на старости лет да польстись на его богатства *(Островский, "Бедность не порок")*
> - Я шутить ведь не умею и вскочи ему на шею *(Ершов, "Конек-Горбунок")*

Shakhmatov argued that both this form and verbial interjectives you mentioned in the other question have taken the function of old Slavic aorist (now extinct in Russian), being close to it phonetically.

Comment: How to know whether "хвать", "глядь" belong to this tense or are interjectives?

Comment: Does "сообрази он вовремя..." belong here?

Comment: @Anixx: no, *хвать* and *глядь* in this tense would be *(возьми да) схвати, (возьми да) взгляни*. These are verbial interjections (*глагольные междометия* or *междометные формы глагола*). Vinogradov did not draw a sharp line between verbial and intejective meanings of this form: *Уже почти за пределами междометий, на границе категории глагола, располагаются "междометные глагольные формы", употребляемые обычно или особенно часто в значении прошедшего времени совершенного вида (с ярким экспрессивным оттенком мгновенности)*

Comment: @Anixx: no, *сообрази он вовремя* conveys subjunctive mood, not paste tense. Russian imperative is generally very diverse. Vinogradov: *В русском языке основная форма повелительного наклонения, свободная от императивной интонации, выходит далеко за пределы императивных синтаксических конструкций. Сочетаясь с личными местоимениями и существительными в именительном падеже, в некоторых синтаксических условиях она выражает разнообразные модальные значения, близкие к кругу значений условно-желательного наклонения.*